# Best way to store input values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

What's the best way to store input values?

Suppose the user need to input the following fields: `Description`, `Quantity` and `Value`.

These will be inserted multiple times, and later the program will do some calculations with `Quantity * Value` and the sum all the products of each item.

Should I use lists to store the items? Or is there a better way to make it?

Comment: if each instance of description quantity and value are linked then yes a list would be a viable option, or better yet, making an object class and creating a list of objects

Comment: Too subjective. Please put more information about these fields.

Answer (score 1):

As people have said, you need to provide more context because there are many ways of doing this. Here is one possible way:

```
fieldnames=["Description", "Quantity", "Value"]

database=[]

def get_input():
    print("-"*20)
    new_item = {}
    for x in fieldnames:
        v=input("Enter {}:".format(x))
        new_item[x]=v

    return new_item


for i in range(3):
    database.append(get_input())



for entry in database:
    print("-"*20)
    for key, value in entry.items():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, value))
```